# How to insert a node in BST using iterative method?

Tags: binary-search-tree

**This it what i tried to implement**

```
struct bstnode* insert(struct bstnode* root, int data){
   struct bstnode* temp = getnewnode(data);

   struct bstnode* temp1=root;
   while(1){
       if(temp1 == NULL){
          temp1 = temp;
          if(root == NULL) root = temp;
          return root;
       }
       else if(data<=temp1->data)
          temp1 = temp1->left;
       else
          temp1 = temp1->right;   
    }
}
```

what's wrong with this solution. I have tried to make link of new node to its desirable position by traversing

Answer (score 0):

To create a BST, the new node `temp` shall be attached to left branch as `temp1->left = temp;` or to right branch as `temp1->right = temp;`.

**Step 1** - before search to the left branch, check if NULL and assign the new node.

```
else if(data<=temp1->data) {
    // check the left node
    if (temp1->left==NULL) {
        // attach the new node to left  
        temp1->left = temp;
        return (root);  
    }
    // otherwise continue
    temp1 = temp1->left;
}
```

Instead of:

```
   else if(data<=temp1->data)
      temp1 = temp1->left;
```

**Step 2** - same check for the right branch.

```
else {
    // check the right node
    if (temp1->right==NULL) {
        // attach the new node to right 
        temp1->right = temp;
        return (root);  
    }
    // otherwise continue
    temp1 = temp1->right;
}
```

Instead of:

```
   else
      temp1 = temp1->right;
```

Comment: But if there is temp1->left = null then temp1 is set null and in another turn  for loop, null is passed through another if condition and links will be changed respectively

Comment: @kunal_goyal, if `temp1->left` the new node `temp` will be linked to as described in the **Step1** ==> `temp1->left = temp;` then `return (root);`.